# How to create xml elements when they are missing with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have three xml structures that need to be cleaned and homogenized by creating an element if it is missing or by selecting it if already exists.

Structure A has most of elements that I need:

```
<biblStruct>
           <analytic>
              <title type="label">Gronemann/Maaß/Peters/Schrader 2001</title>
              <title type="titel">Körper und Schrift. Beiträge zum 16. Nachwuchskolloquium der
                 Romanistik, Leipzig, 14.-17. Juni 2000</title>
              <idno>6677</idno>
              <idno>6677</idno>
              <author>
                 <persName>Gronemann, Claudia;Maaß, Christiane;Peters, Sabine A.;Schrader,
                    Sabine</persName>
              </author>
           </analytic>
           <monogr>
              <title type="label">Gronemann/Maaß/Peters/Schrader 2001</title>
              <title type="titel">Körper und Schrift. Beiträge zum 16. Nachwuchskolloquium der
                 Romanistik, Leipzig, 14.-17. Juni 2000</title>
              <idno type="standortsign">UB Bern;SUB Göttingen</idno>
              <author>
                 <persName>Gronemann, Claudia;Maaß, Christiane;Peters, Sabine A.;Schrader,
                    Sabine</persName>
              </author>
              <imprint>
                 <publisher>Romanistischer Verlag</publisher>
                 <pubPlace>
                    <placeName>Bonn</placeName>
                 </pubPlace>
                 <date>2001</date>
              </imprint>
           </monogr>
           <relatedItem type="enhalt">
              <ref>Objekt 3257 / Biographien-Werke</ref>
           </relatedItem>
           <note type="faustdb">biogra</note>
           <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>
           <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>
           <note type="erstellt">
              <date>2016-09-18T00:00:00.000</date>
           </note>
           <note type="letztebearb">
              <date>2016-09-18T00:00:00.000</date>
           </note>
        </biblStruct>
```

Whereas structure B is missing the element `publisher` inside `imprint`:

```
<biblStruct>
           <analytic>
              <title type="label">Volmer 2001</title>
              <title type="titel">Die Gebrechen des Lebens. Zur Körpererfahrung in
                 Korrespondenzen des 18. Jahrhunderts</title>
              <idno>3257</idno>
              <idno>3257</idno>
              <author>
                 <persName>Volmer, Annett</persName>
              </author>
           </analytic>
           <monogr>
              <title type="label">Volmer 2001</title>
              <title type="titel">Die Gebrechen des Lebens. Zur Körpererfahrung in
                 Korrespondenzen des 18. Jahrhunderts</title>
              <idno type="standortsign">UB Basel: AP IX 5844</idno>
              <author>
                 <persName>Volmer, Annett</persName>
              </author>
              <imprint>
                 <biblScope unit="sammelwerkin">Objekt 6677 / Biographien-Werke</biblScope>
                 <biblScope unit="sammelwerkseiten">138-149</biblScope>
              </imprint>
           </monogr>
           <note type="faustdb">biogra</note>
           <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>
           <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>
           <note type="erstellt">
              <date>2005-01-19T00:00:00.000</date>
           </note>
           <note type="letztebearb">
              <date>2016-10-10T00:00:00.000</date>
           </note>
           <note type="kategorie">Briefkultur, Netzwerke,
              Transfer;Wissen(schaft)sgeschichte/Medizin</note>
        </biblStruct>
```

I would like to be able to create this `publisher` element nested inside `imprint` when it is missing only -- I am dealing with a huge list that contains very diverse entries.

The same applies to structure C, which is lacking even more elements:

```
<biblStruct>
           <analytic>
              <idno>24587</idno>
              <idno>24587</idno>
              <author>
                 <persName>Person aus Ref-Tabelle</persName>
              </author>
           </analytic>
           <note type="faustdb">Publik</note>
           <note type="objektart">Rezensionen</note>
           <note type="objektart">Rezensionen</note>
        </biblStruct>
```

In this case I would like to add after the following elements `analytic`:

```
<monogr>
              <imprint>
                 <publisher></publisher>
              </imprint>
           </monogr>
```

So the output should be:

```
<biblStruct>
           <analytic>
              <idno>24587</idno>
              <idno>24587</idno>
              <author>
                 <persName>Person aus Ref-Tabelle</persName>
              </author>
           </analytic>
           <monogr>
              <imprint>
                 <publisher></publisher>
              </imprint>
           </monogr>
           <note type="faustdb">Publik</note>
           <note type="objektart">Rezensionen</note>
           <note type="objektart">Rezensionen</note>
        </biblStruct>
```

It does not matter if elements are empty at the moment. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Remember all these xml entries are in the same file and I cannot sort them out yet so I need to create the required elements taking into account if they already exist or they do not exist yet. Thanks!

Comment: One of the fundamental design principles around XML is that elements can be missing without ill-effects and that the absence of an element indicates that the associated data is not available. It's not by accident that querying a document with XPath for elements that don't exist is not an error, but simply returns an empty list. Creating empty elements "just because" would go against that principle. It can be done, no problem, but the question is - do you really need it? What for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to create them because I am hoping to to fill in the elements with values in the future. At the moment they can be empty but I need them for validation purpusoses, etc. Thanks.

Comment: "*I need to create the required elements taking into account if they already exist or they do not exist yet*" Or you could simply create all of them, regardless of whether they exist or not - then populate those that do exist with the corresponding values. There is a reason why a template is called a template.

Comment: @Antonio Just as well you can simply create them when you need them, instead of filling them when you need them. So there's still no real reason to keep empty elements around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I tried this and it worked for the first case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei" version="2.0"
xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:imprint[not(./tei:publisher)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="tei:publisher"> </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Just FYI, there is no need to say `<xsl:element name="tei:publisher">`. Just say `<tei:publisher>` directly. Much shorter and much easier to read.

Comment: Also, I'd probably use `<xsl:if test="not(tei:publisher)">...</xsl:if>` inside a regular template for `tei:imprint`. That way you would have less special cases and you would have complete control over the order of the children.

Comment: I don't think this does what you want it to do.Should it not copy the other elements that do exist inside `imprint`? Anyway, I suspect that if you continue with this method, your stylesheet will soon grow into an unmanageable forest of exceptions.